# Use of hot belts for weight loss

Tags: health-risk, physical-therapy

There are a lot of hot belt available in the market which claims that by wearing such belt one can loose weight  and make himself good looking and physically fit by  pressing abdomen in. They explain that as one wear hot belt it rapidly caused sweating, in this way  these hot belts lost calories and fatness around our body.
Before buying this hot belt I want to ask is these belts produce same results as it is told on media.Is there any side effects of these hot belt on our health???

Answer (score 3):

The premise of these hot belts is based on a fallacy.  Sweat is [composed](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijac/2015/164974/) primarily (99%) of water with small amounts of minerals and traces of hundreds of other compounds floating around in blood.  The amount of calorie containing molecules shed via sweat is quite small.

Using a hot belt or other mechanism to induce profuse sweating, will cause a person to lose water weight, which will normally return when they absorb enough water to bring their body back into osmotic balance.

A person who sweats extensively is at risk of dehydration, and depending on how they rehydrate possibly an electrolyte imbalance.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR: These kinds products don't give the results they claim and are certainly not a healthy way to lose weight.**

When you workout, you burn calories, approximately **85% of which are exhaled**. The remaining 15% of the calories come out as sweat.

When you put on a belt like this, you'll lose a lot of water, which makes you weigh less when you step on a scale, but you don't physically lose any weight. As soon as you drink water, you'll regain what you lost.

Furthermore, sweating a lot without drinking water might put you at risk of dehydration, so I don't recommend that.

Comment: TLDR : Every product claiming you will loose weight or build muscle without working out or without changing your diet is lying

Comment: @P154 Basically, yes :)